# C# How to speed up ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Tags: threadpool

I created a server, which listens on a port for an incoming connection, then call ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to create a server thread to handle the client request.

I then have 400 threads trying to connect to the server at the same time. I found that the server handles them one by one, at roughly 0.5 second each.

How do I tell ThreadPool **NOT TO** think for 0.5 second before launching a new thread? This server is meant to be a high-throughput server.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you're trying to achieve high throughput, you should be aware that thread-per-connection is rarely the right way to achieve it. You should be looking at async options.

Comment: I asked a colleague who used async in our production code. Now I know exactly what you meant. Many thanks for pointing me to the right direction! I is invaluable!